# Will two unpublished research papers boost the chances of my scholarship application being reconsidered?

Tags: graduate-admissions, graduate-school, funding

The scholarship committee denied my application yesterday. Fortunately, the committee gave me five months, to produce new credentials that would merit its reconsideration of its decision.

Thus far, I have found two additional unpublished research papers that I co-authored with two other people. The problem is that  these research papers are more related to my line of work than to the graduate program I applied to.

Will these two research papers boost the chances of my application being reconsidered?

Comment: That is up to the committee. It can't hurt, but I doubt that it will count for a lot.

Answer (score 2):

Since you have been encouraged to submit more material, these papers can only help. With the limited data you have it's impossible to estimate how much.

Five months sounds to me as if they expect (or would welcome) some new work, not just old work you found in your records.